# Why does my async not work well with the third call but perfect with the first two

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, path

So I have a mind boggler, my app grabs a git repo (simple-git) then makes an npm i on the files inside (shelljs) and then zips using archiver. Of course it needs to be async but the first part and second part work however at the point of archiving it fails (the next step is for axios to await the zip being done), also before this when I ran the zip code with the grabbing repo code it would create the zip file in the correct root directory but now does it in the folder directory instead (repo/folder) , the zip is empty now though instead of zipping the other contents. Please assist if you can
The code:

```
// // //Make call
function makeCall() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(
      git()
        .silent(true)
        .clone(remote, ["-b", branch])
        .then(() => console.log("finished"))
        .catch((err) => console.error("failed: ", err))
    );
  });
}

//Make NPM Modules
async function makeModules() {
  await makeCall();

  const pathOfFolder = path.join(__dirname, "folder/sub");
  shell.cd(pathOfFolder)

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(
      shell.exec("npm i"));
  });
}

async function makeZip() {
  await makeModules();

  const output = fs.createWriteStream(`${branch}.zip`);
  const archive = archiver("zip");

  
  output.on("close", function () {
    console.log(archive.pointer() + " total bytes");
    console.log(
      "archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed."
    );
  });

  archive.pipe(output);

  // append files from a sub-directory, putting its contents at the root of archive
  archive.directory("folder", false);

  // append files from a sub-directory and naming it `new-subdir` within the archive
  archive.directory("subdir/", "new-subdir");

  archive.finalize();
}

makeZip();
```

Comment: The archiver code works perfect when isolated and the repo is already brought in

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it, moved to other files and set path correctly